# Malloc accessibility between two functions

Tags: c, thread-safety, malloc

I'm writing a variant of the producer-consumer problem with multi threading. I'm trying to use a queue to store the "produced" items until they get "consumed" later on. My problem is that when the consumer thread runs, it only processes the most recent item added to the queue (rather than the oldest item on the queue). Further, it processes that item repeatedly (up to the number of items on the queue itself).

I think that my problem might be that I need to allocate some memory when I push an item onto the queue (not sure about this, though). But then, I need a way to refer to this memory when that item is about to be consumed.

Anyway, here is a paired down version of my program. I realize that what I am posting here is incomplete (this is an infinite loop), but I'm trying just show the part that is relevant to this issue. The functions queue_push() and and queue_pop() are well tested, so I don't think that the problem lies there. I'll post more if needed.

Can anyone see why my consumer thread only processes the newest queue item? Thank you!

```
sem_t mutex;
queue q;

FILE* inputFPtr[10];

char host_in[BUFFERSIZE];
char host_out[BUFFERSIZE];

void* p(void* inputFile) {

    while (fscanf(inputFile, INPUTFS, host_in) > 0) 
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        queue_push(&q, host_in); //this function pushes the hostname onto the back of the queue   
        fprintf(stdout, "Produced: %d) %s\n", i, host_in);
        sem_post(&mutex);        
     }

    fclose (inputFile);
}

void* c() {

    while (TRUE)
    {        
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        sprintf(hostname_out, "%s", (char *) queue_pop(&q));
        printf("%s\n", host_out);
        sem_post(&mutex);
    }

}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int i;
    pthread_t *th_in[argc-2];
    pthread_t *th_out[2];

    for (i = 0; i < (argc-2); i++) {
        th_in[i] = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)); 
        inputFPtr[i] = fopen(argv[i+1], "r");
        pthread_create (th_in[i], NULL, p, inputFPtr[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        th_out[i] = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
        pthread_create (th_out[i], NULL, c, null);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (argc - 2); i++) {
        pthread_join(*th_in[i], 0);
        free(th_in[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (2); i++) {
        pthread_join(*th_out[i], 0);
        free(th_out[i]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Uhm, as is quite often the case, the "important" code, such as the "queue_push" and "queue_pop" appears to be missing. I bet that's where the code is going wrong...

Comment: We need a full NON-working ( ;) ) code to diagnose the problem... i can't see any issue with the above code

Comment: I can't see why your consumer thread only processes the newest queue item because I can't see your code. ;)

Comment: Do *not* mutilate your question by, for example, removing the code that you asked about.  Do not modify your question so as to render existing answers meaningless, either.  If you need to amend your question (which is a legitimate action), do so respecting the efforts of those who have tried to help you.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't realize that I had deleted my post. I was trying to paste in additional code. Didn't mean to violate any SO rules or disrespect any of the responders.

Comment: BTW, I discovered my issue. The code for the queue functionality (not posted here) was written intending that the queue would hold pointers to the strings rather than the strings themselves. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to post you code. However from your description, it seems like all the queue members point to the same memory block. This is why all your pops result with the same item. 
The answer to you question is YES. You need to allocate memory for each one of the items and free it after it was "consumed".

Try to post some code for more specific answers...

Comment: The answer to his question is *maybe* - if he has a bounded queue with all storage pre-allocated he may not need to `malloc` or `free` anything. We need the code to provide any sort of insight.

Comment: Yes, I know. It is just a guess according to the symptoms described by @usr55410.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying to re-post my code with some changes and I seem to have deleted it entirely. My bad.